# Parse.com licensing with decompilation of code for binding the java libraries to C# with Xamarin

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, parse-platform

**Forgive me** because I don't really know where to ask this question, but I assume it would be really helpful to a lot of people to know the answer. If I shouldn't have asked it here, please redirect me to a better site to ask it at. Thank you.

Anyway, so I use Parse in a lot of my applications particularly on Android and web-based apps as a backend for data. It's a great service and they provide great documentation, and I love it. However, I recently switched from native java on android to C# with Xamarin.Android. I was very happy to find that Parse had an existing sdk for Xamarin.Android apps! **Unfortunately, I needed Push Notification functionality which hadn't been implemented in that sdk**, but had been well documented and maintained in the native java/android sdk for Parse.

So after reading every comment on Parse's forums about my issue, **I looked into binding the java/android libraries from Parse to Xamarin's C# for Android**, because it seemed to be the only solution other than using their REST API. Xamarin has a really nice tool for binding java to C#, but, and I could be wrong, **my understanding is that the Xamarin binding tool must be decompiling the java source from the native android parse sdk, parsing through it, and then creating C# wrappers around it.**

However, if you go onto Parse's site and look at their license, it says that **Parse's code cannot be decompiled**. On the other hand, when you go onto Xamarin, they have iOS bindings for Parse that they appear to have binded themselves to C#, and are **distributing it on Github**. Also, on Parse's forums whenever someone suggested to bind the sdk, no one ever responded saying that it wasn't allowed.

So my questions are:

*How is it possible that Xamarin can bind libraries without decompiling the native java?*

*Is it legal to bind the Parse/Android sdk from java to C# and use it in a production application or distribute it?*

Thanks again!

Comment: Your second question seems to assume that publicly available licenses are the only kind of license one might get. Presumably the folks at xamarin have a *contract* with parse.com

Comment: Ah interesting. That would clear things up. But it still doesn't explain why Parse wouldn't outlash when they saw that people were doing that.

Comment: Using the bindings provided by Xamarin under contract? Again, this is speculation, but I would guess it's because they're allowed under the contract.

Comment: No I mean there were two separate people who suggested doing it on Parse's forums to the public and there was no response from any Parse rep. I guess they could have contracts too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i know Java Binding Libraries decompile nothing. It creates a binding project that automatically wraps the library with C# wrappers based on a declarative approach. It wraps only public classes and methods.

Here is example of generated wrapper code for YouTubePlayer

```
[Register ("com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer", "", "Google.Android.Youtube.Player.IYouTubePlayerInvoker")]
public partial interface IYouTubePlayer : IJavaObject {

    bool HasNext {
        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.youtube.player']/interface[@name='YouTubePlayer']/method[@name='hasNext' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register ("hasNext", "()Z", "GetHasNextHandler:Google.Android.Youtube.Player.IYouTubePlayerInvoker, Google.Android.Youtube.Player")] get;
    }

    bool HasPrevious {
        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.youtube.player']/interface[@name='YouTubePlayer']/method[@name='hasPrevious' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register ("hasPrevious", "()Z", "GetHasPreviousHandler:Google.Android.Youtube.Player.IYouTubePlayerInvoker, Google.Android.Youtube.Player")] get;
    }

    bool IsPlaying {
        // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.youtube.player']/interface[@name='YouTubePlayer']/method[@name='isPlaying' and count(parameter)=0]"
        [Register ("isPlaying", "()Z", "GetIsPlayingHandler:Google.Android.Youtube.Player.IYouTubePlayerInvoker, Google.Android.Youtube.Player")] get;
    }

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.youtube.player']/interface[@name='YouTubePlayer']/method[@name='addFullscreenControlFlag' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='int']]"
    [Register ("addFullscreenControlFlag", "(I)V", "GetAddFullscreenControlFlag_IHandler:Google.Android.Youtube.Player.IYouTubePlayerInvoker, Google.Android.Youtube.Player")]
    void AddFullscreenControlFlag (int p0);

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.youtube.player']/interface[@name='YouTubePlayer']/method[@name='cuePlaylist' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]"
    [Register ("cuePlaylist", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", "GetCuePlaylist_Ljava_lang_String_Handler:Google.Android.Youtube.Player.IYouTubePlayerInvoker, Google.Android.Youtube.Player")]
    void CuePlaylist (string p0);

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.youtube.player']/interface[@name='YouTubePlayer']/method[@name='cuePlaylist' and count(parameter)=3 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String'] and parameter[2][@type='int'] and parameter[3][@type='int']]"
    [Register ("cuePlaylist", "(Ljava/lang/String;II)V", "GetCuePlaylist_Ljava_lang_String_IIHandler:Google.Android.Youtube.Player.IYouTubePlayerInvoker, Google.Android.Youtube.Player")]
    void CuePlaylist (string p0, int p1, int p2);

    // Metadata.xml XPath method reference: path="/api/package[@name='com.google.android.youtube.player']/interface[@name='YouTubePlayer']/method[@name='cueVideo' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='java.lang.String']]"
    [Register ("cueVideo", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", "GetCueVideo_Ljava_lang_String_Handler:Google.Android.Youtube.Player.IYouTubePlayerInvoker, Google.Android.Youtube.Player")]
    void CueVideo (string p0);
```

You can learn more from [architecture description](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/architecture/) and [java binding description](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/)